How to configure cloudflare protection (proxying) for firebase v2 functions
I'm desperately trying to configure some rate limiting on firebase functions - more specifically v2 functions.
According the the online knowledge I should take the function public url (for now let's ignore the fact that is publicly available on the web anyway) an set up a cname record in cloudflare to point to that function. For the sake of example:
cname | host: api | https://*****-****-function-name-*****-***.a.run.app
Unfortunately this doesn't work. When requesting I get a google branded 404 page. What can I do make proxying work?

Have you solved the issue?

No, didn't solve this yet.
